# stability of $(0,0)$ for $\dot{\theta} = y$ and $\dot{y} = -\sin\theta$

Tags: geometry, nonlinear-system, plane-geometry

Given the system $\dot{\theta} = y$ and $\dot{y} = -\sin\theta$.

For the fixed point $(0,0)$ I can see through linearisation that the flow corresponds to a centre which moves anticlockwise

Why is this centre stable? at $y=0$, $\dot{\theta}=0$ but i cant seem to go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that 
$$ \frac{d}{dt}(\frac12 y^2-\cos \theta) = y\dot{y} + \sin\theta\,\dot{\theta} = 0$$
Can you continue?

Comment: This quantity is conserved, Do i take V equal to whats inside the brackets and use that as a lyapunov fct. $\dot{V} = 0$ and $V \geq 0$ for all points except the origin. And so its stable but not asymptotically stable

Comment: That's correct.